# Diophantine linear Equation Gaussian Integers

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, diophantine-equations, euclidean-algorithm

We know that $ax+by=c$ with $gcd(a,b)=1$ could be solved over $\Bbb Z$. Supposing if $a,b,c\in\Bbb Z[i]$, is there an analogous framework to find $x,y\in\Bbb Z[i]$ (at least of minimum norms)?

Comment: You can extend the Euclidean algorithm  so to compute the Bezout identity exactly the same as for integers, e.g. as in [this answer.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/85841/242) Ditto for polynomials over a field or any other domain that has a (constructive) Euclidean algorithm.